# laravel uploading image getting error with Method [Save]

Tags: laravel-5, file-upload, image-uploading

Please help me with this error:

I have an edit/update student profile picture in my school project. Now this is what I've got in my laravel controller: In my controller, sometimes update from user will not include the picture, so I've put two queries if the user update the profile with no image, then the else query will be executed.

Here is all my code, my view and my Controller.

I got this error when I executed the code:

```
Method [save] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\UserStudentController].
```

Any suggestions with these error?

```
public function editMyStudent(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [            
            'editstudfname' => 'required',
            'editstudmname' => 'required',
            'editstudlname' => 'required',
            'editstudparentnum' => 'required|min:12|numeric',
            'editstudsubcat' => 'required',
            'datetimepicker3' => 'required',            
            'file2.*' => 'max:2000|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',

        ], [
            'editstudfname.required' => 'First name is required.',
            'editstudlname.required' => 'Last name is required.',
            'editstudmname.required' => 'Middle name is required.',            
            'editstudparentnum.required' => 'Parent contact number is required.',            
            'editstudparentnum.min' => 'Parent contact number must be 12 digits.',                        
            'editstudparentnum.numeric' => 'Parent contact number must be numeric.',            
            'editstudsubcat.required' => 'Course is required.',
            'datetimepicker3.required' => 'Birthdate is required.',            
            'file2.*.image' => 'Selected file must be image.',
            'file2.*.mimes' => 'Selected file must be jpeg,png,jpg.',
            'file2.*.max' => 'Image size must not greater 2MB.'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {    
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
        } else {
             if ($request->hasFile('file2')) {
                $image = $request->file('file2');
                $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $destinationPath = public_path('/image_files');
                $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
                $this->save();
                $response = DB::table('student')
                ->where('student_id', $request->editstudid)
                ->update(array(
                'course_id'=>$request->editstudsubcat,            
                'fname'=>$request->editstudfname,            
                'lname'=>$request->editstudlname,            
                'mname'=>$request->editstudmname,            
                'bdate'=>$request->datetimepicker3,            
                'photo_path'=>$name, 
                'gender'=>$request->editstudgender,            
                'contact'=>$request->editstudparentnum,                        
                'stud_status'=>$request->editstudstatus,                        
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')  # \Datetime()
                ));
                return response()->json(['success'=>$response]); 
            }
                $response = DB::table('student')
                ->where('student_id', $request->editstudid)
                ->update(array(
                'course_id'=>$request->editstudsubcat,            
                'fname'=>$request->editstudfname,            
                'lname'=>$request->editstudlname,            
                'mname'=>$request->editstudmname,            
                'bdate'=>$request->datetimepicker3,            
                'gender'=>$request->editstudgender,            
                'contact'=>$request->editstudparentnum,                        
                'stud_status'=>$request->editstudstatus,                        
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')  # \Datetime()
                ));
                return response()->json(['success'=>'Successfully Updated']);  
        }
    }
```

I have this also in my ajax :

```
function edituserStudent(e) {    
      e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($("#editStudentFrm")[0]);     
        formData.append('file', $('#file2')[0].files);

        $.ajax({         
            url:  "{{ route('user.editmystud') }}",     
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "JSON",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) { 
                if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                $('.print-error-msg-editmystud').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
                $('.print-error-msg-editmystud').addClass('alert alert-success');
                $('.print-error-msg-editmystud').find("ul").html('');
                $('.print-error-msg-editmystud').css('display','block');
                $(".print-error-msg-editmystud ul").append('<li class="tick">'+data.success+'</li>');
                $('#editStudentFrm')[0].reset();                                
                }else{
                printErrorMsgCat(data.error);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I am guessing that the method $this->save(); doesn't exist?

Comment: @bumperbox yes sir. thanks for reply.